# Why is the modification of string literal allowed via char*, despite the fact that it points to a read-only memory?

Tags: c++, memory, operating-system, string-literals

Well I have been doing a lot of programming recently, but this simple question never crossed my mind.
Suppose I have the following snippet of code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
   char* p="hello";
   p[0]='y';
   std::cout<<p;
}
```

I am aware that by the [C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf)(section 2.14.5 paragraph 11) it is stated that this is an undefined behavior. However, when I still think about it I just can't make sense of this. As far as I am aware, string literals are allocated in read-only memory, so when we declare pointer to that part of the memory, it should whether tell me that I cannot do this type of conversion, but in some compilers it just ends up with warning, and the following code still compiles and prints `yello`.

However, if we have modified the code above by this little detail.

```
char arr[]="hello";
```

The program above would make sense to me, because as far as I understand, what arr does is coppying the string into a memory allocated on stack(correct me if I am wrong).

So my question is, beside the fact that the compiler only is aware of the fact that `p` is not a pointer to const, so it allows modification, how is it allowed in the very-low level handling, shouldn't the OS prohibit the modification of `p[0]` in the program above, because it points to a read-only memory block?

Comment: *"when I still think about it I just can't make sense of this."* -- welcome to undefined behavior.

Comment: There's no guarantee that string literals are stored in read only memory.

Comment: Well, although it called so, it should make some sense in some context, right?

Comment: It's not allowed.  You are in Undefined Behavior land, where a working program is a valid result.

Comment: Since c++11 this should not compile.

Comment: @KarenBaghdasaryan The result of undefined behavior does make sense **if** you understand all of the decisions that a compiler makes behind the scenes. One of those decisions is whether or not to put your string literal in read-only memory. If it chooses not to do so (perhaps because it sees that you are trying to modify it), then everything deduced from your assumption (that the string is in read-only memory) is invalid. Another possibility: it might choose to optimize away saving the `'y'` to `*p`, but still produce the output **as-if** it had.

Comment: " shouldn't the OS prohibit the modification of p[0] " --> C/C++ do not even require an OS.

Comment: Sometimes it is interesting to speculate why a particular something happened as a result of undefined behavior. However, I've found that one consequence of the as-if rule is that it is rarely interesting to speculate why something did *not* happen (such as the OS stepping in) as a result of undefined behavior. The answer usually boils down to "the compiler optimized away the Bad Thing".

Comment: Just to be clear, it *is* allowed by the compiler (see my answer for detail). However, the compiler is free to do whatever it wants in the resultant program, including formatting all your local drives while playing `malicious_laughter.mp3` :-) So, even if *allowed,* still a bad idea.

Comment: Do not tag questions with both C and C++ unless you are asking about differences or interactions between the two languages. They are different languages with different answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As far as I am aware, string literals are allocated in read-only memory.

Then I would suggest the possibility that you are not *totally* aware :-)

The standard doesn't actually *mandate* that string literals are read-only, just that attempting to modify them is undefined behaviour (UB).

One of the *possible* outcomes of UB is that it may actually *work* sometimes. That doesn't, of course, make it any less of a bad idea, since it may work or not work in any manner at any time.

Comment: Looks like this covers everything, thank you.

Comment: "One of the possible outcomes of UB is that it actually works!"  I personally prefer, "... no failures were observed.  This time."